# Periodic extension for Heat Equation with time-dependent source

Tags: fourier-analysis, periodic-functions, heat-equation, partial-differential-equations

I have the PDE

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} - tu, \quad 0<x<1$$

subject to the boundary conditions (BCs) $u(0,t)=0, u_x(1,t)=0$ and initial condition (IC) $u(x,0)=f(x)$.

I have found the general solution using separation of variables

$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \sin \left[ \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right) \pi x \right] e^{-t \left[ \left(n+\frac{1}{2} \right) \pi \right]^2+\frac{t}{2}}$$

which then using the IC gives

$$u(x,0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} \sin \left[ \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right) \pi x \right] = f(x)$$

The next question is to state how the BCs gave a periodic extension of $f(x)$ with period $4$ and the piecewise definition of it over $-2<x<2$. This has had me confused for hours as I thought the period is $2$ as $\ell=1$. Does anyone have an idea of what to do next?

Comment: You need a Fourier sine series of $f$ to compare coefficients and to determine $a_n$. I don't understand the periodic extension part of your question.